# Problema com link na lista

Tags: html, css

Estou com um problema quando coloco um link dentro de uma celula da minha lista, por algum motivo a primeira celula fica como eu quero e as demais ficam todas como se fossem o mesmo link. Como pode ver abaixo
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyqqe.png)

SERVIÇOS DE TORRE COM O DOUGLAS (PHOUSS)

```
        <ul class="lista__servico">
            <li>
                <h2>Torre Normal</h2>
                <p class="valor__servico">R$ 10,00</p>
                <a href="https://wa.me/+558193874114?text=Ol%C3%A1%20tenho%20interesse%20no%20servi%C3%A7o%20de%20TORRE%20NORMAL!">
                    <img class="icone__servico" src="/clz/img/delivery-box.png">

            </li>
            <li>
                <h2 class="titulo__lista">Torre Hard Auto</h2>
                <p class="valor__servico">R$ 20,00</p>
                <p class="texto__servico">Clique no Icone para fazer o pedido</p>
                
                

            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Torre Hard Manual</h2>
                <p class="valor__servico">R$ 30,00</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Torre Hell 10 &#9733; </h2>
                <p class="valor__servico">R$ 30,00</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Torre Hell 15 &#9733;</h2>
                <p class="valor__servico">R$ 40,00</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Torre Hell 20 &#9733;</h2>
                <p class="valor__servico">R$ 50,00</p>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </section>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: QUero colocar uma imagem como link dentro de uma celula da minha lista, porem quando faço isso as demais celulas da lista se tornam um link igual da imagem que inseri na primeira celula

Answer (score -2):

Você esqueceu de adicionar o "< / a >", se pretende colocar a imagem como link clicável, deve seguir uma lógica desse tipo
"< a href="seulink" > < im > < / a >"
(tire os espaços estranhos dentro das tags)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).